# Can't tag local Documents folder : Error -8058

Tags: macos, finder, finder-tag

I wanna use Finder tags to organise my Mac with using "Groupe by" feature.
Everything is fine, except for one folder : the "Documents" folder, located in my personal folder.
(Note : this folder is on my local machine and is not synced with iCloud "Documents" folder.)

Whenever I try to tag this folder, Finder raises an error : "The operation can't be completed. An unexpected error occured (Error code -8058)."

[image: Error screenshot - FR]

Is this folder corrupted ? What can I do to solve this problem ?

Thanks !

System Information :

- macOS Big SUr 11.5.1
- MBP 13" 2018, 4 Thunderbold ports
- 2,3 GHz Intel Core i5 4 core
- 16 Go 2133 MHz LPDDR3
- Finder version 11.5

What I tried :

- Restart computer
- Remove `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist` and his lockfile + Restart

I observed :

- Unlike any other folder, I can't view/edit acces rights for my Documents folders (see pic)

[image: Folder details]

Comment: Could you try searching the web again for something like "8058 finder error"? I find it hard to believe you could not find any information about this error code. It's ok if you find solutions and don't know how to apply them, or if they don't work, but please include your attempts and prior research in your question. Thank you!

Comment: Found some points at https://www.tenorshare.com/mac-os/how-to-fix-mac-error-code-8058.html#p1. Can't remove this folder entirely as it's the system main Documents folder, it could run into problems. Also, I've no file corrupted anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without getting into the details of why in **macOS Big Sur** you cannot apply a **Tag** to the **Documents** *folder*, and until there is a more direct solution, here is a workaround that worked for me.

Note that these directions assume that one is the **Admin** and logged into an **Admin** *account*.

Please read this entire answer before proceeding and make sure you have a full backup of the entire contents of the **Documents** *folder* before processing these directions!

1. From **Finder**, in your **Home** *folder*, create a temporary *folder* outside of the **Documents** *folder* to move the entire contents of your existing **Documents** *folder* to.
2. Press the *keyboard shortcut* **⇧⌘.** to show hidden **Finder** *items*, if they are not currently showing.
3. Move the entire contents of your existing **Documents** *folder* to the temporary *folder*, the one you just created for this task, by using **⌘A** to select all **Finder** *items*, then drag and drop the **Finder** *items* into the temporary *folder* created for this task.
4. In **Terminal**, from your **Home** *directory*, create a *directory* named `D` using the following *command*: `mkdir -m 0700 D`
5. In **Finder**, in your **Home** *folder*, add the **Tag(s)** to the **D** *folder* that you would like to have on the **Documents** *folder*.
6. Make sure you have moved the entire entire contents of your existing **Documents** *folder* to the temporary *folder* created for this task. (**Warning!**)
7. In **Terminal**, from your **Home** *directory*, run the following *commands*:

- <sup>**NOTE**: This will **delete** the existing **Documents** *directory* and rename the **D** *directory* to: **Documents**</sup>

```bash
chmod -N Documents
rm -r Documents; mv -v D Documents
chmod +a "everyone deny delete" Documents
killall Finder
```

8. Back in **Finder**, move the entire contents of your previous **Documents** *folder*, from the temporary *folder* created for this task, to the new **Documents** *folder*.
9. Delete the temporary *folder* previously created for this task after making sure it's empty.
10. Press the *keyboard shortcut* **⇧⌘.** to hide hidden **Finder** *items*, if that be your preference.

That's it, you are done, and the **Documents** *folder* has **Tag(s)**.

---

**Notes:**

If/when you want to change/modify/remove the **Tag(s)** on the **Documents** *folder*, you will need to replicate the directions herein.

These directions were tested in a clean install of **macOS Big Sur** 11.5.2, with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

Additionally, I do not use **iCloud** and I'm logged in using a local **Admin** account without being signed in using my **Apple ID**, if any of that might matter to the successful execution of these directions.

[image]

Comment: That works like a charm ! Thank you very much ! I'm curious about the technical reasons of why this folder cannot have tags, if you have more information